# Latex TikZ Help Drawing Fold and Hopf Bifurcations

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to recreate these generic bifurcation diagrams for a LaTeX report that illustrate fold, sub-critical and super-critical Hopf bifurcations. I can't figure out how to do so by looking at other TikZ codes.[image: fold bifurcation] [image: sub-critical Hopf][image: super critical Hopf].

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE. For future question please always provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) and give as much information as possible.

Comment: Drawing a figure look like the ones you posted is an easy task with TikZ. However, if you need an illustration for some concrete example, then you need to provide exact statement, or better, the formulae for the bifurcation diagram (ít may be a parabola, may be not)

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have something to start with:

I am not a mathematician so I have to guess what kind of function this is.

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        samples=1000,
        xlabel=$x$,
        xtick=\empty,
        ytick=\empty,
        ylabel=$r$,
        xmin=-2,xmax=6,
        ymin=-2,ymax=6,
        axis lines=middle,
        x label style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north, below=-5mm},
        minor x tick num=3,
        minor y tick num=3,
        ticklabel style={font=\small},
        enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
        ]

        \draw[blue,dashed] \pgfextra{
            \pgfpathellipse{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{3}{0}}
            {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0.5}{0}}
            {\pgfplotspointaxisdirectionxy{0}{1.7}}
        };
    \addplot[,smooth,domain = 0:5,name path = A,red]{x^(1/2)};
    \addplot[red,smooth,dashed,domain = 0:5,name path = A,red]{-x^(1/2)};

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am not a mathematician either so I can't say for sure but I think it's not for any specific function per se, it just shows the trajectory that a solution of a dynamical system takes as one of its input parameters are varied.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible starting point using `pgfplots` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-,very thin},
    samples=200,
    xtick=\empty,   xlabel=$c$,
    ytick=\empty,   ylabel=$x$,
    label style={below left},
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, brown},
    domain = -4:0,
    enlarge x limits={0.2,upper},
    no marks
    ]
\addplot    {sqrt(abs(x))};
\addplot [dash pattern=on 5pt off 2pt]  {-sqrt(abs(x))};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    axis line style={-,very thin},
    samples=200,
    xtick=\empty,   xlabel=$\gamma$,
    ytick=\empty,   ylabel=$r$,
    label style={below left},
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, brown, dash pattern=on 5pt off 2pt},
    domain = 0:4,
    enlarge x limits={0.2,lower},
    no marks
    ]
\addplot    { sqrt(x)};
\addplot    {-sqrt(x)};

\scoped[every path/.style = {very thick, brown, dash pattern=on 5pt off 2.5pt}]
{
\draw           (-2,0) -- (0,0);
\draw [solid]   (0,0) -- (4,0);
%
\draw[blue]     (2,0) ellipse [x radius=0.5, y radius=sqrt(2)];
}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1; BTW, I never saw `\scoped` - very cool.